No space above Subtitle heading
at one specific part of my paper, there is no space above the subtitle. Everywhere else it seems fine. I presume it is because of a nastly two column equation at the bottom of the page. Any ideas on how to get this right? Thanks
\documentclass[
    superscriptaddress,
    amsmath,amssymb,
    aps,
    pre
]{revtex4-2}

\begin{document}
Using this asymptotic of $P(Q,k)$ in \eqref{eqn:trajsumevap} yields the large deviation asymptotic \eqref{eqn:largedeviation} for $P(Q)$ with $\phi(q)=\min\{\phi_0(q), \ldots, \phi_N(q) \}$ leading to the expression \eqref{eq:ldf eva exact}.

\subsection{Large deviation for the mortal Brownians}
\label{sec:stickyderivation}

Here, we present a derivation for the piece-wise large deviation function discussed in \ref{sec:multisticky}.
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}.

@EmanueleNardi Hi, I can surely add it but the problem seems to occur only at one particular instance of subititle. Spacing above every other subtitle seems fine.

If the spacing issue occurs only for one particular subtitle, it might be caused by some local formatting or an unusual input in that section. Could you try to isolate the problem by creating a minimal working example (MWE) containing just that subtitle and its surrounding context? That will help identify the problem.

It has often happened in the past that, while trying to isolate a problem to ask for help, I ended up finding the issue myself and answering my own question :)

You missed the \begin{document} in the MWE. Also, what is the intended purpose of \sref?

That just references a different section title. I think this problem is simply not possible to solve. This section is the penultimate subitltle of the paper and there is a huge equation (double coloumned in single column template) at the end of the page where my paper ends. If even very small space is somehow added, the whole formatting gets messed up. I think latex already found that this is the best way.

It seems that this code snippet doesn't quite replicate the issue as described.

\documentclass[
    superscriptaddress,
    amsmath, amssymb,
    aps,
    pre
]{revtex4-2}

\begin{document}
Using this asymptotic of \(P(Q,k)\) in~\eqref{eqn:trajsumevap} yields the large deviation asymptotic~\eqref{eqn:largedeviation} for \(P(Q)\) with \(\phi(q) = \min\{\phi_0(q), \ldots, \phi_N(q) \}\) leading to the expression~\eqref{eq:ldf eva exact}.

\subsection{Large deviation for the mortal Brownians}% <- removes space between target and label
\label{sec:stickyderivation}

Here, we present a derivation for the piece-wise large deviation function discussed in~\ref{sec:multisticky}.
\end{document}


Yeah, I don't understand why. It seems like the equation has nothing to do with the spacing. Even when I remove the equation, spacing for only this particular subtitle seems messed up. Maybe something to do with two column template? Also thanks for taking a look

I removed everything below the subtitle and still same problem

If you have the paper on Overleaf I can take a look if you like

Try to gradually remove items above the subtitle until the issues become apparent.

I really wish I could share the overleaf link but without my collaborators' permission, I;m not sure if it's correct....really sorry

But it seems to me that latex is doing some weird auto spacing for this penultimate subtitle. I say this because if i remove some text or add some text, everything becomes fine. Only in some range of amount of text, there is this problem

I made this proposal just to try to solve the problem as soon as possible, there is nothing to worry about, I don't understand anything about physics, I'm a computer scientist
